# Cut a 3D surface with many planes with vtk

Tags: c++, vtk

I used `vtkcutter` to resolve this problem but the vtkcutter give the chance to cut my 3D surface with only one plane. In my problem I need to cut my 3D surface with many planes, so how can I create many planes with the `vtkcutter`?

Comment: Could you show us what you already tried?

Answer (score 2):

Try this (works on a vtkUnstructuredGrid 'ugrid'). It creates 10 slices between points p01 and p02 and appends the slices to one instance of vtkPolyData. It's written in python though..

```
polys = vtk.vtkAppendPolyData()

Nslices = 10
p01 = (0,0,0)
p02 = (0,1,0)
for ks in range(Nslices):
    p0 = (0,p01[1]+(p02[1]-p01[1])/float(Nslices)*ks,0)
    plane = vtk.vtkPlane()
    plane.SetNormal(0,1,0)
    plane.SetOrigin(p0)

    cut = vtk.vtkCutter()
    cut.SetInput(ugrid)
    cut.SetCutFunction(plane)
    cut.Update()
    output = cut.GetOutput()
    polys.AddInput(output)
```

Comment: how I can display this planes

Comment: you can, for example, write the poly data to a vtp file and visualize it using paraview. `writer = vtk.vtkXMLPolyDataWriter();
    writer.SetFileName('afile.vtp')
    writer.SetInput(polys)
    writer.Write()`